# Socket.io/Node.js & SCTP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sctp

I am developing an web application that will use web sockets to dynamically update the website for the user. The idea is to have changes in the back-end engine be dynamically transmitted. In order to do that, I want to use a Node.js server as a link between the web browser and back-end engine. Unfortunately, Node.js/JavaScript does not support SCTP sockets, which is what the back-end engine is using. Can you think of any way around this? It would be a shame if I couldn't use Socket.io and would have to deploy my own Javascript plugin & Java websocket server.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the SCTP part in C or C++ and then write an [addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) to make it available in Node.js. I am currently trying that for one of my projects using SCTP.

Of cource, this is not super elegant, not very portable and it is some extra work, but if you really want to use Node.js, this is one of the possible ways...

Comment: We are working with Python/gevent & uwsgi now, there is a nice SCTP wrapper, although it does have some problems.